# Create List Email

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I need create an Email List.
For each Folder, I need get all email from owners.
But, I have an error in listRequest.Email = reader["Email"].ToList();
The error is in "ToList()", I'm declaring namespace System.Collections.Generic but don't resolves.

```
public class ListRequest
{
    public List<string> Email { get; set; }
    public string FolderAccess { get; set; }
}

public List<ListRequest> PreencheValores(SqlDataReader reader)
{
    var lista = new List<ListRequest>();
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        var listRequest = new ListRequest();
        listRequest.Email = reader["Email"].ToList();
        listRequest.FolderAccess = reader["FolderAccess"].ToString();
        lista.Add(listRequest);
    }
    return lista;
}
```

Comment: can you post the error you are getting?

Comment: What type of database field is the "Email" field? You can't just convert anything to a list...

Comment: What is the format of the value of `reader["email"]`?

Comment: @CaioVJesus89 Did you add watch for `reader["Email"]` what it said?

Comment: @AmitApollo This is the error: "'object' does not contain a definition for 'ToList' and no extension method 'ToList' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

Comment: @Tim Email is an varchar in database. An can't use ToList() in C#. It's the error!

Comment: @CaioVJesus89 Did you add watch for reader["Email"]. Could you paste the watch value here??

Answer (score 2):

Below statement is not valid.

```
listRequest.Email = reader["Email"].ToList();
```

Using SqlDataReader you can read only single element but not list like what you did to retrieve folder access.

```
listRequest.FolderAccess = reader["FolderAccess"].ToString();
```

One thing you could do is retrieve email addresses as comma separated values and then split them. Also consider using string[] instead of List

```
public class ListRequest
{
    public string[] Email { get; set; }
    public string FolderAccess { get; set; }
}


public List<ListRequest> PreencheValores(SqlDataReader reader)
{
    var lista = new List<ListRequest>();
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        var listRequest = new ListRequest();   
        if(reader["Email"] != null)   
          listRequest.Email = reader["Email"].ToString().Split(',');
        if(reader["FolderAccess"] != null)
          listRequest.FolderAccess = reader["FolderAccess"].ToString();
        lista.Add(listRequest);
    }
    return lista;
}
```

Comment: Did not work for what I need! =/ I have an page with Name Folder and one CheckBox and an Button "Send". My Event Send have send an email for each row with checkbox checked is true. But I have 2 or more owner email for each row, in my DataBase. My problem is get all email for each row but not duplicate information in my page.

Comment: I get what you are saying, as mentioned you cant retrieve multiple records using ToList(). You need to write database query that gives multiple records as single record with comma separated email addresses. Check "for xml" clause in sql, to know how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

`reader["Email"]` is an object.  There is no method `object.ToList()`

If it is supposed to be a delimited string, I recommend doing a `ToString()`, then `Split()` before your `ToList()`.

Example:

```
listRequest.Email = reader["Email"]
    .ToString()
    .Split(new [] {","}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    .ToList();
```

Comment: "reader["Email"] is not an object" - um, do you mean "*is* an object"?

Answer (score 0):

reader["Email"] is not a collection. Its gets the value of the specified column in the native format given the column name.

So do this

```
var lstEmail = new List<string>();
using (connection)
{
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT Email FROM TableName;",connection);                                                                        
    connection.Open();
    SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

    if (reader.HasRows)
    {
       while (reader.Read())
       {
            lstEmail .add(reader.GetString(0))
       }
    }
    reader.Close();
}
```